# VS debugger do not works as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

When I debug my ASP.NET app and execution breaks at break point I can't read `type` variable using Debug Watches. Why? I get error

```
type    The name 'type' does not exist in the current context
```

The code works fine, the problem only in debugging, I can't read all variables while debugging.

```
var converterSubClasses = new List<Type>();
GetClassHierarhy(ref converterSubClasses, converterClass);

foreach (var type in converterSubClasses)
{
  /* break point here */  var classProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  /* skip code */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you mouse over the word type and see that value that way?

Comment: @JesusRamos I do not get any popup message while move on type word as I get on other variables.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh(button with green arrows in circle) value in watcher?...By the way, while searching about your problem, I found something new and interesting for me - [How to track an object which is Out of Scope while Debugging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120011/How-to-track-an-object-which-is-Out-of-Scope-while), so sort of thanks for you :)

Comment: @Reniuz Yes, tried, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Are you debugging code compiled in Release mode? Depending on the optimizations the compiler used the variable `type` may not actually be there. Confirm you're debugging against Debug compiled code and try then. (I've had loops not make sense and entire sections get jumped when trying to debug in release mode.)

Comment: I can confirm that I am debugging in Debug mode.

Comment: Are you debugging against IIS or are you debugging locally? If you're debugging against IIS you may need to redeploy the newly compiled debug code.